# Two domains that point to the same IP have different outputs?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have two domains registered with ***godaddy.com***, lets just call them `domainone.example` and `domaintwo.example`.
I also have one hosting account with ***godaddy.com*** that I set up with my purchase of `domaintwo.example`.
Both of the domain names set up with the same nameservers and IP.
When I go to `domainone.example` it shows me the website I have.
When I go to `domaintwo.example` it shows me a page that says 'pageok'.
When I go to the ip of the server, it shows me 'pageok'.
When I ping to `domainone.example` and `domaintwo.example`, they both have the same IP address.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, this is my first time dealing with non-dedicated hosting.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? This is quite normal with HTTP.

Comment: Through domainone.com I get <!doctype html><html>...(my website). Through domaintwo.com I get only "<pre>pageok</pre>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague.  You need to clarify why you are trying to accomplish.

However, I will take a guess as to what I think you are saying.

Firstly, domain names are not limited to one IP address.  Just like a house has a unique address, there can be one or multiple people living there.  In this case, people are websites.  This is why when you ping both websites, you get the same address.  Each person/website has a unique identity and are totally separate from each other.

Secondly, it sounds like you are asking how to modify the website on domaintwo.  I am not familiar with godaddy, however there should be either a web interface on a management site, or some other form of management, like a FTP site.  Since it sounds like you dont know, your best best is to call godaddy for support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you work me up at the multiple domains at one IP thing, I had just forgotten that my website a shared IP host, not dedicated as I was used to.